# How to handle explicit solvent molecules when calculating energies of reactant molecules in isolation

Tags: density-functional-theory, geometry-optimization, orca, explicit-solvent

When determining the energy barrier, it is recommended to compute the energies of reactant molecules in isolation to account for the entropy change of forming the reactant complex (hence factoring this into the energy barrier). If I have explicit solvent molecules (using both implicit and explicit solvent) with two reactants, should I treat the solvent molecules as isolated reactants as well? (i.e. ran each solvent molecule in isolation?)

Comment: To clarify the question a little bit, I think what you mean is: when calculating a reaction $A(S)_m + B(S)_n \to C(S)_k + (m+n-k)S$ (where $S$ is the solvent), and $m+n-k\neq 0$, whether we should treat the energy of $(m+n-k)S$ as $m+n-k$ times the energy of $S$, or the energy of a solvent cluster $(S)_{m+n-k}$ . Is this what you mean? Or alternatively, one may calculate the energy of $C(S)_k + (m+n-k)S$ as the energy of $C(S)_{m+n}$, i.e. use more than enough solvent molecules to solvate $C$ to balance the equation. Then the question becomes which one of the three approaches is the best.

Comment: @wzkchem5 For the most part, the first option. For A(S)m+B(S)n, should I take A(S)m as a reactant entity or should I separate it as A and m(S) (And if so, should I do one isolated solvent molecule multiplied by the number of solvent molecules? as you succinctly put with the equations). Also can I ask how you input equations in?

Comment: $A(S)_m$ should definitely be taken as a single entity, otherwise the whole point of explicit solvation is lost. Explicit solvent molecules are used to describe the first (occasionally also the second) solvation shell of $A$, which implicit solvation models do not describe well. Therefore they must be carried around by $A$ throughout the calculation. The rule that reactants must in general be calculated separately is irrelevant here, since $A$ is always in contact with the solvent, while non-solvent reactants were not in contact with each other before the reaction.

Comment: You can input equations in TeX. Just input your equation in TeX format and surround it with a pair of dollar signs.

Comment: There's also an ORCA chat room on this site.

Comment: @wzkchem5 it looks like your comments were sufficient for the OP (the OP hasn't visited MMSE for 4 months, but visited SO only 18 days ago). Do you think you can write an answer to help remove this from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @NikeDattani will do